# Bottom elements overlap the Google logo on the Maps

Tags: java, google-maps, maps, overlap

Good afternoon!
We are developing a new product for the App Store.
Now we are faced with an issue that, we hope, will not cause problems when releasing the Application and will not affect its performance.
We have a Google Maps screen. On the design layout, I could show you that the [bottom elements overlap the Google logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2mRk.png). There is a state of this screen when these elements open and become even larger.
Question: Is it a problem that the Google logo is not fully visible or partially visible?
Our suggestions on how we can resolve this issue, if this is a problem:

1. To create a state of this screen, when by clicking on an empty space, the elements will completely disappear.
   Then there will be two states of this screen: a) where the Google logo is visible, but the elements is not; b) where the Google logo is not visible, but these elements are visible
2. To attach the Google logo to this element, its upper left border. Raise the logo together with the element.
   Please give an advice on how we should be or suggest your options for resolving this issue.
   Thank you in advance!
   Regards,
   Arina Lebedeva

Comment: According to the [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license.), under 3.2.2 (b) Attribution, Customer will not modify, **obscure**, or delete such attribution.

Comment: Good afternoon!
Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, this is understandable and we did not plan any illegal actions. There is just an example of an Airbnb app that is implemented so that the bottom elements overlap the map logo when expanded. Here we are at a loss, how can we implement it?